# JQuery remove doesn't work properly

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am running into a problem where `$('element').remove();` doesn't work.
I have read many other answers where there are syntax problems and the click isn't registered on the button correctly.

I am having a different problem. The click is working but the only thing removed is *newRowDiv*.

It starts out `<newRowDiv><child><child><child></newRowDiv>` 
and ends up 
`<child><child><child>`
*newRowDiv* is gone but the children are just left there.
The weird thing is the code works fine until I add the `trigger('create')`

This is about what my code does

```js
buildRows = function(){
            //Adds the new div to the placement div
            var placementDiv = $('#placementDiv');
            placementDiv.append("<div class='newRowDiv'></div>");
            //Adds the child elements to the new div
            var newRowDiv = $(".newRowDiv:last");
            newRowDiv.append("<label>Title</label>");
            newRowDiv.append("<input>");
            newRowDiv.append("<a id='plusButton'>Plus</a>");

            //Adds the click event to the new plus button (Works fine)
            newRowDiv.find('#plusButton').click(function (event) {
                var button = $(event.target);
                //Adds the delete button (Works fine)
                var newRowDiv = button.parent('.newRowDiv');
                newRowDiv.append('<a id="deleteButton">Delete</a>');
                //Adds the click event to the button (Works fine)
                newRowDiv.find('#deleteButton').click(function (event) {
                    //Removes the parent newRowDiv and all child elements (Doesn't work)
                    var button = $(event.target);
                    button.closest('.newRowDiv').remove();
                });

                //Removes the plus button (Works fine)
                button.remove();

                //Adds the new rows section (Works fine)
                buildRows();
                //Without this the new elements don't display correctly
                //With this the remove only removes the element and leaves it's children behind
                placementDiv.trigger('create');
            });
        }
buildRows()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="placementDiv">
    </div>
```

Edit: 
The code snippet is running. I am only hitting the problem on my stuff when I run trigger.('create') which is adding some jquery mobile formatting

Edit 2: It appears to have something to do with jquery mobile's popup formatting. Because it works fine in the code snippet without a popup and it works fine in my original code before I added trigger('create')

Comment: does this function get used multiple times to add rows? If so, then you're adding multiple buttons with the same ID. That's invalid HTML. IDs must be unique. There's a good chance it's causing your click events not to fire, because the element you're attempting to define them on is invalid. Sort that out and then see if you still have a problem. And your snippet doesn't compile - are you missing some brackets from the end?

Comment: If you `bind` inside another `bind` your event will only be bound after you click the initial click, on the parent binding. Move the second `click()` outside, on the same level with first and it will start working.

Comment: @Andrei the bind is working fine. I verified using the javascript debugger in chrome. and the click event was caught

Comment: @darthNater If you say so, you probably know better. It's your script, after all. Take care.

Comment: @ADyson. I changed the code so the  generated ids are now unique. Same problem. The click is triggering I have caught it in the javascript

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I believe the bind is working fine because the click is for sure being triggered. Things are happening. The remove doesn't remove everything though

Comment: @darthNater can you update the snippet so it actually compiles, please, then we can see what your intentions are. At the moment, there's a lot of nesting and it's difficult to see where you meant it to begin and end. It could be important. e.g. right now it looks like you call buildRows recursively, forever. But I'm sure that's not the case really. There are some closing brackets missing somewhere, but I can't be 100% where you want them to be.

Comment: The buildRows is called when I click on the plusbutton for the current section being built. I'm not sure how to add a javascript library to the code snippet. It appears to be erroring out on the $(#placementDiv)

Comment: I can't test it, since you're not showing your markup. But I added two possible variants. But, really now, we can't code blindly. Give us a [mcve]! Re-test the first script too, as it was missing a bracket.

Comment: I'm not asking you to make it run fully, but at least add the missing brackets so that the javascript doesn't throw a syntax error. There's a }); missing somewhere

Comment: Regardless, what you should do is `console.log(event.taget);` inside your nested `click()`. That will give you the answer.

Comment: @darthNater I've just ran your questions' code and it works. What's the matter? Have you fixed it when you put the missing part? I don't get it :)

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I wasn't able to figure out why it wouldn't work with the trigger('create'), so I added data-role='none' and manually added the items that the trigger('create') added. It now works as expected. Thanks for trying to help

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you found a way. Happy coding! :: }<(((*> ::)

Answer (score -2):

Try using .delegate() instead of .click().

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ this method is deprecated. It was replaced by `.on` way back in jQuery 1.7.